# React Native Android Unable to resolve all files error

Tags: android, react-native

I created a new project with `react-native init Proj` and then `run react-native run-android`.Also, I installed native base through `react-native install --save native-base` and then react-native link. I am getting the below error:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   'app:debugCompileClasspath'

[image]

Did I miss out on something?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this script:

`npm run react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

It helped me when I had resources issues with `React Native`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this script:

```
 cd android and ./gradlew clean 

 1. mkdir android/app/src/main/assets 

 2. react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res 

 3. react-native run-android
```